# Creating Android Native Extension and getting: Permission Denial: starting Intent.. on second activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, permissions, air-native-extension

I am successfully calling my first Activity from my AIR Native Extension, however, when I try to call the second one, I am getting the Permission Denial error (see logcat screenshot).  I have tried everything I have found suggested on this site, so posting question.

```
02-12 15:43:22.430: I/ActivityManager(271): START {act=android.intent.action.RUN cmp=com.cno.android.map/.AddMarkerActivity (has extras) u=0} from pid 14173
02-12 15:43:22.440: W/ActivityManager(271): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN cmp=com.cno.android.map/.AddMarkerActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{4147a718 14173:air.TestAndroidExtension.debug/u0a75} (pid=14173, uid=10075) not exported from uid 10072
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.cno.android.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<!-- End of copy. -->

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.cno.android.map.InitMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_init_map" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.cno.android.map.AddMarkerActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Things to note:
I first tried AddMarkerActivity without any intent-filter defined. Not having ANY luck, I began experimenting with the RUN action.  I have commented everything out in AddMarkerActivity except for one logcat message that says "HELLO" in the onCreate method.  As you can see my Activity is not duplicated in the manifest and exported is set to true.**

**And finally, here is how I am calling the Activity:**

```
public class AddAnnotationFunction implements FREFunction {

public static final String TAG = "AddAnnotationFunction";
public final static String EXTRA_MARKER = "com.cno.nativemap.functions.marker";

@Override
public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.cno.android.map", "com.cno.android.map.AddMarkerActivity");
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting Map Activity- add marker");
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.RUN");
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MARKER, new GeoMarker(args));

    context.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    return null;
}
```

}